# Airflow template not rendering when used with PostgresOperator when trying to pass value from XCom

Tags: airflow

I've written a pretty simple DAG that first does some python operations and afterwards should update a Database-Table with the returned value. Here is the DAG-Code:

```
tmpl_search_path = Variable.get('sql_path')

dag = DAG('test_dag',
          description='',
          schedule_interval='@daily',
          template_searchpath=tmpl_search_path,
          start_date=datetime(2017, 3, 20),
          catchup=False)

# Returns a string
t1 = PythonOperator(task_id='t1',
                    python_callable= someCallable,
                    dag=dag)


update_monitoring_table_last_run = PostgresOperator(task_id='update_monitoring_table_last_run',
                                                    sql='update_monitoring_table_last_run.sql',
                                                    postgres_conn_id='conn_id',
                                                    params={"script_name": t1.task_id},
                                                    dag=dag)

update_monitoring_table_status_msg = PostgresOperator(task_id='update_monitoring_table_status_msg',
                                                      sql='update_monitoring_table_status_msg.sql',
                                                      postgres_conn_id='conn_id',
                                                      params={"script_name": str(t1.task_id),
                                                              "status_msg": "{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='return_value') }}"},
                                                      dag=dag)

t1 >> update_monitoring_table_last_run >> update_monitoring_table_status_msg
```

The PostgresOperator for `update_monitoring_table_last_run` works completely fine, so no worries there. How `update_monitoring_table_status_msg` does not work as intended.
Here is the underlying SQL-template:

```
UPDATE table
SET status_msg = '{{ params.status_msg }}'
WHERE script_name = '{{ params.script_name }}'
```

The rendered template though looks like this:

```
UPDATE bi.bi_scripts_monitoring
SET status_msg = '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key='return_value') }}'
WHERE script_name = 'script_name'
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
UPDATE bi.bi_scripts_monitoring
SET status_msg = 'StringThatWasReturnedByPythonOperator'
WHERE script_name = 'script_name'
```

Why is it not rendering the value here? I tried the same with a `BashOperator` and there the template was rendered correctly? 
Any help would be appreciated. I think I'm missing something XCom specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`params` keyword is not templated, hence you will need to change your file to following:

```sql
UPDATE table
SET status_msg = '{{ params.status_msg }}'
WHERE script_name = '{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="return_value") }}'
```

Comment: Oh thats too bad. Thank you very much anyways